# Create an array of number of occurrences from another array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, data-structures

I have two array which looks like

```
var monthNames = [ "January", "January", "January", "April", "April", "December", "August", "August", "November", "November", "November", "December" ];

var monthRange = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
"July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
```

Now I am wondering how should I work in JS so that I would get a new array back, again with 12 elements in it (one for each month) and get a count of it. So it will be like this -

```
[3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 1]
```

Here count is in the order of the `monthRange` which gives count for each month in `monthNames` .

So here

```
January : 3, 
April: 2, 
December: 1,
August: 2, 
November: 3, 
December : 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would do it:

```
var counts = monthRange.map(function(val) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0, j = monthNames.length; i < j; i++) {
        if (val === monthNames[i]) count++;
    }
    return count;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `map` over the `monthRange` and then filter the `monthNames` to return the number of occurrences of each month:

```
monthRange.map(function(month) {
    return monthNames.filter(function(n) { return n === month }).length;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using underscore you can do it like this:

```
_.reduce(array, function(memo, month) { 
    memo[month] = (memo[month] === undefined ? 0 : memo[month]) + 1; 
    return memo
}, {})
```

In your case, it can look something like

```
   var countMonths = function(array, m) {
       return  _.reduce(array, function(memo, month) { 
           memo[month] = (memo[month] === undefined ? 0 : memo[month]) + 1; 
           return memo
       }, m)   
   } 

   var memo = countMonths(monthNames, {})
   memo = countMonths(monthRange, memo)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `Object` to keep track of frequency:

```js
var freq = function(list) {
  var o = {};
  var l = list.length;
  var v;
  while (v = list[--l])
    o[v] = o[v] !== undefined ? o[v] + 1 : 1;
  return o;
};

console.log(freq(["January", "January", "January", "April", "April", "December", "August", "August", "November", "November", "November", "December"]));

alert(JSON.stringify(freq(["apple", "mangoe", "apple"])));
```

```html
Open console...
```